# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails and Entity hierarchy mustn't change

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

This is a tough one. I know there is plenty of questions like that here, but my problem is, that I'm not allowed to change/edit the class heirarchy, because this is an already productive application, which if changed fundamentally, must be tested thoroughly and this will cost to much. Even if there's something stupid in the hierarchy, I'm not allowed to change it, because the whole application might stop functioning, and it will take long hours to bring it back on. (Nasty, I know). So, basically, what I am looking for here is some kind of workaround, that will give me a chance to delete entity instances without constraint violation and changing the hierarchy.

On top of the hieararchy is an entity "Request", that splits further in "Import Request" and "Export Request". So ImportRequest extends Request and ExportRequest extends Request. Every ExportRequest has a Set of Position, which is defined like that:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "antrag_id")
@ForeignKey(name= "FK_EXPAN_POS")
public Set<Position> getPosition() {
    try {
        position.size();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // NO Need just make hibernate load the list
    }

    return position;
}
```

Position is just another Entity. And every ImportRequest has a Set of ImportPosition, like that:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "antrag_id")
@ForeignKey(name= "FK_IMPAN_POS")
public Set<ImportPosition> getImportPosition() {

    try {
        importPosition.size();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // hallo 
    }
    return importPosition;
}
```

whereas ImportPosition extends Position.

Every Position has only one Probe assigned to it, which is defined like that:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "probe")
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_POS_PROB")
public Probe getProbe() {
    return probe;
}
```

Implicitly evert ImportPosition will have one too, because it extends the Position. Which also works on a database level.

I'm deleting an IMportRequets with a method like this:

```
@Transactional
public void cleanArchivedRequests() {
    List<Integer> archivedRequestList = requestDao.retrieveAllArchivedRequests();
    for (Integer antragId : archivedRequestList) {
        Request requestToDelete = requestDao.loadById(requestId);
        requestDao.delete(requestToDelete);

        StringBuffer protocolEntry = new StringBuffer("Request mit der ID: ");
        protocolEntry.append(requestId);
        protocolEntry.append(" gelöscht!");
        protocol(protocolEntry.toString());
    }
}
```

Apparently Hibernate has problems deleting the Probe which is referenced by an ImportPosition in an ImportRequet, because I get this:

```
 [java] java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`position`, CONSTRAINT `FK_POS_PROB` FOREIGN KEY (`probe`) REFERENCES `probe` (`id`))
```

requestDao is injected via Spring with applicationContext-daos.xml in my class, where the method "cleanArchivedRequests" is.

So my question is, given that hierarchy, is it possible at all to successfully delete the Probe instances from the ImportPosition and if so, how would that work. I've already tried to delete the Probe instances first and than the ImportRequest, but that didn't work, supposedly because the whole thing happens in one transaction. Or at least this is my explanation.

PS. The whole Stacktrace goes like this:

```
 [java] java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`position`, CONSTRAINT `FK_POS_PROB` FOREIGN KEY (`probe`) REFERENCES `probe` (`id`))
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1257)
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:943)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2507)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2725)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 [java]     at $Proxy33.cleanArchivedRequests(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at de.fast.hama.util.HamaRequestArchiver.main(HamaRequestArchiver.java:66)
 [java] 2012-06-22 17:56:07,925 [DEBUG] - com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException:85 - Attempted to convert SQLException to SQLException. Leaving it alone. [SQLState: 23000; errorCode: 1451]
 [java] java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`position`, CONSTRAINT `FK_POS_PROB` FOREIGN KEY (`probe`) REFERENCES `probe` (`id`))
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1257)
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:943)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2507)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2725)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 [java]     at $Proxy33.cleanArchivedRequests(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at de.fast.hama.util.HamaRequestArchiver.main(HamaRequestArchiver.java:66)
 [java] 2012-06-22 17:56:07,925 [DEBUG] - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.statusOnException:126 - Testing a Connection in response to an Exception:
 [java] java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`position`, CONSTRAINT `FK_POS_PROB` FOREIGN KEY (`probe`) REFERENCES `probe` (`id`))
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1257)
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:943)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2507)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2725)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 [java]     at $Proxy33.cleanArchivedRequests(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at de.fast.hama.util.HamaRequestArchiver.main(HamaRequestArchiver.java:66)
 [java] 22.06.2012 17:56:07 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
 [java] WARNUNG: SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
 [java] 22.06.2012 17:56:07 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
 [java] SCHWERWIEGEND: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`position`, CONSTRAINT `FK_POS_PROB` FOREIGN KEY (`probe`) REFERENCES `probe` (`id`))
 [java] 22.06.2012 17:56:07 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
 [java] SCHWERWIEGEND: Could not synchronize database state with session
 [java] org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
 [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2507)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2725)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 [java]     at $Proxy33.cleanArchivedRequests(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at de.fast.hama.util.HamaRequestArchiver.main(HamaRequestArchiver.java:66)
 [java] Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`position`, CONSTRAINT `FK_POS_PROB` FOREIGN KEY (`probe`) REFERENCES `probe` (`id`))
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1257)
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:943)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
 [java]     ... 23 more
 [java] 2012-06-22 17:56:07,941 [DEBUG] - org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollbackOnCommitException:871 - Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
 [java] org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:636)
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:789)
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:663)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 [java]     at $Proxy33.cleanArchivedRequests(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at de.fast.hama.util.HamaRequestArchiver.main(HamaRequestArchiver.java:66)
 [java] Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
 [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2507)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2725)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
 [java]     ... 8 more
 [java] Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`position`, CONSTRAINT `FK_POS_PROB` FOREIGN KEY (`probe`) REFERENCES `probe` (`id`))
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1257)
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:943)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
 [java]     ... 23 more
 [java] 2012-06-22 17:56:07,941 [DEBUG] - org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback:670 - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@1c10834]
 [java] 2012-06-22 17:56:07,956 [DEBUG] - org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion:730 - Closing Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@1c10834] after transaction
 [java] 2012-06-22 17:56:07,956 [DEBUG] - org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession:789 - Closing Hibernate Session
 [java] 2012-06-22 17:56:07,956 [DEBUG] - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.trace:1644 - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1a37fac [managed: 10, unused: 9, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@f1b25e)
 [java] Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:636)
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:789)
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:663)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
 [java]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 [java]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 [java]     at $Proxy33.cleanArchivedRequests(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at de.fast.hama.util.HamaRequestArchiver.main(HamaRequestArchiver.java:66)
 [java] Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
 [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2507)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2725)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
 [java]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
 [java]     ... 8 more
 [java] Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`position`, CONSTRAINT `FK_POS_PROB` FOREIGN KEY (`probe`) REFERENCES `probe` (`id`))
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1257)
 [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:943)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
 [java]     ... 23 more
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem Hibernate inheritance is the issue here... you're trying to remove rows from the Probe table that are referenced via foreign keys in the Position table (and class hierarchy thereof).

I presume since you are using the `@ForeignKey` annotation that you use a script generated from your Hibernate objects to generate your database DDL scripts.  Those constraints by default do not specify any behavior on reference deletion, hence the error you're seeing.  You can either modify the constraints to specify an @OnDelete behavior, or explicitly set the foreign key reference to null for every Probe object you delete.